# How to create a temporary Primary Key Azure TSQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, telerik, radgrid

I need to check for possible duplicate addresses in a table called User.  To do so I am using a JOIN then comparing tables for the first set of street numbers in an address string.  For example "123 First Street" and "123 First St." need to be identified as a possible match/duplicate.

However I also need the Telerik RadGrid displaying the records to have a unique DataKeyName to identify the row for a double click javascript function to work.

Because of the JOIN my normal Primary Key's are duplicated in "both" tables a and b.  How can I create a temporary psuedo Primary Key using SQL just so my datagrid can identify the row double clicked on?

```
    try
    {
        //Select Query to populate the RadGrid.   
        string selectQuery =

            "SELECT " +
            //We rename the dbo.User table as "a" then rename it again as "b" so we can look for duplicate Street Address numbers
            "a.Id AS LeftID,a.DateSubmitted AS LeftDateSubmitted,a.Updated AS LeftUpdated," +
            "a.Status AS LeftStatus,a.StreetAddress AS LeftStreetAddress," +

            "b.Id AS RightID,b.DateSubmitted AS RightDateSubmitted,b.Updated AS RightUpdated," +
            "b.Status AS RightStatus,b.StreetAddress AS RightStreetAddress " +

            //We join the 2 virtual dbo.User tables where table b Id's are greater than table a meaning b records are newer
            "FROM [User] a JOIN [User] b ON b.Id > a.Id AND " +

            //LEFT selects the left most characters (usually numbers) in the StreetAddress field string before the space ' '
            //and eliminates the rest of the address isolating just the street address numbers for matching
            "LEFT(a.StreetAddress,CHARINDEX(' ',a.StreetAddress)) = LEFT(b.StreetAddress,CHARINDEX(' ',b.StreetAddress)) " +

            //Don't show orange or blue status records
            "AND b.Status != 'Orange' AND a.Status != 'Orange' AND a.Status != 'Blue' AND b.Status != 'Blue' " +

            //If a b record (newer) is red then ignore because it is completed and ignore a records (oldest) older than 90 days
            "WHERE a.DateSubmitted >= (GetDate() - 90) AND b.Status != 'Red' " +

            //Show newest records first
            "ORDER BY b.DateSubmitted DESC"
            ;

        SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, SqlConnection);
        SqlDataAdapter.Fill(dtTable);
        RadGrid1.DataSource = dtTable;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to generate a random ID for each row, add the NEWID() function to your column list.

For example:
SELECT NEWID() AS PsuedoKey, * FROM ...

Comment: This looks good at a glance @dgiard I'll try it out and let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: You rock sir! Thanks @dgiard!